# How to Export (from Blender) & Import an Alembic File into Xcode

Tags: xcode, animation, scenekit, blender, alembic-format

Our team is developing an iOS app in Xcode and using Blender to create models and animations.  We haven't been able to find a way to bake a fluid simulation and export into a format that Xcode understands and plays the animation.

We've successfully imported Alembic (.abc) files found online into Xcode that play their animation from a Mesh Sequence Cache Modifier, but our own liquid simulation when baked and exported as Alembic only appears as a static mesh in Xcode, but still use a Mesh Sequence if re-imported to Blender.  We're not sure what's different in our files from the ones we've found online.

Could you please explain what settings should be used to bake, export, and import an Alembic file? So that our artist can make our final animations work in the app.

**Notes**

1) We applied the import process as stated by gchiste on Apple Developer Forums ([here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/365180#365180)). However, she doesn't go into detail on how to export an Alembic file. Only the way to import an Alembic file is stated. We can assume import process works for Xcode (as stated by gchiste) because some of the random .abc files we found online worked within Xcode.

2) What I mean with worked is that Alembic files played their animations when viewed from Xcode's Visual Editor. Also, when the project ran (at run time)

3) I know there isn't code here. However, since this issue is related to Xcode, SceneKit, 3d game development and causing a software development issue I thought it makes sense to ask this question here.